# Is there a way to make a constant "dark mode" by using local Storage?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been making a small site with a default 'light mode' and a dark mode button to change it to dark mode for night users. I wanted to make the dark mode constant using localStorage from JS, so when you press it once and go to another page on the site, it stays dark mode. But I can't seem to get it to work.

When I set the localStorage key 'mode' to 'dark', it defaults to light mode when I go to another page in that site.

Here is the js code:

```
let mode;
mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');

if (mode = 'light'){
    lightMode();
}else{
    darkMode();
}

function darkMode() {
    document.getElementById("title").style.color = "white";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#040040";
    //code...
    document.getElementById("darkmodebtn").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("darkmodebtn").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("darkmodebtn").onclick = lightMode;
    document.getElementById("darkmodebtn").innerHTML = "Light Mode";
    localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark');
    mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
}

function lightMode() {
    document.getElementById("title").style.color = "black";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    //more code...
    document.getElementById("darkmodebtn").style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById("darkmodebtn").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("darkmodebtn").onclick = darkMode;
    document.getElementById("darkmodebtn").innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
    localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light');
    mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
}
```

And here is the html for the button:

```html
<div id="darkmode">
    <button id="darkmodebtn" onclick="darkMode()">Dark Mode</button>
</div>
```

There is one error when I open the any page on the site, which is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at lightMode (script.js:79)
    at script.js:57
```

Which describes the error at the first line in the lightMode function, but I don't know if that's part of the problem or not.

Comment: The error suggests that either your element with the ID `title` or `darkmodebtn` can't be found at the point at which you're running your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check if a condition is `true` or `false`, you have to use `===` to compare them.

```
if (mode === 'light'){
    lightMode();
}else{
    darkMode();
}
```

to fix the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`,

you should place codes after all DOMs are generated,

for example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="title"></div>
        <script>
            // place your code here!
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice there was only one equals sign lol.

And thanks for helping me with the error!

Comment: What I figured out to do was to put the <script> at the bottom of the html instead of in the <head> that way all of the elements load first.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line:

`if (mode = 'light')`

`mode = 'light'` is an assignment, storing 'light' in the mode variable. But for the purposes of the if statement, it's also an expression that evaluates to 'light', which `if` interprets as `true`. Therefore, you'll always be in light mode.

`if (mode === 'light')` is what you want.

Comment: While this is one of the reasons the code doesn't work, this does not answer the question of the `Uncaught TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

You could use two seperate css files for different modes.

```
if(lightmode===true) {
  document.getElementById("stylesheet").setAttrubute("href","light.css");}
else {
  ...//else block
}
```